# Partition a string in Go

Tags: go

How do I get the slices before and after a separator from a string? In Python, I can simply write

```
user, _, domain = "foo@example.com".partition("@")
assert user == "foo"
assert domain == "example.com"
```

Notably, this also works if multiple occurrences of the separator are present in the input, or none at all. How can I split a string that easily in Go?

Comment: Maybe you should tag your question with Python as its probably more interesting to Python/Gophers than just Gophers.

Comment: @miltonb How so, don't *pure* Gophers ever have the need to split a string into everything before and after a separator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with go 1.18, you can use `strings.Cut`

> func Cut(s, sep string) (before, after string, found bool)
>
> Cut slices s around the first instance of sep, returning the text before and after sep. The found result reports whether sep appears in s. If sep does not appear in s, cut returns s, "", false.

Examples:

```golang
strings.Cut("Gopher", "Go") // returns "", "pher", true
strings.Cut("Gopher", "ph") // returns "Go", "er", true
strings.Cut("Gopher", "er") // returns "Goph", "", true
strings.Cut("Gopher", "Badger") // returns "Gopher", "", false
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this helper function which wraps [`SplitN`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#SplitN):

```
import "strings"

func Partition(s string, sep string) (string, string, string) {
    parts := strings.SplitN(s, sep, 2)
    if len(parts) == 1 {
        return parts[0], "", ""
    }
    return parts[0], sep, parts[1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed SplitN allows you to parse at most `n` strings. If you need something simpler for e-mail check, you can try something like the code below. Don't forget to check the error.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "errors"
)

func Separate(str, separator string) (string, string, error){
    sepIndex := strings.Index(str, separator)
    if sepIndex >= 0 {
        return str[0 : (sepIndex)], str[sepIndex+len(separator) : len(str)], nil
    } else {
        return "", "", errors.New("Separator now found!")
    }
}

func main(){
    str := "@xmyname@xample.com"

    fmt.Println("Initial string: ", str)

    p1, p2, err := Separate(str, "@x")
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Slice 1:", p1, "\nSlice 2:",p2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, one can simplify the method signature by simply letting the separator and after-separator parts be empty if the at sign is not found. For emails that doesn't make much sense, but say to split a URL  into protocol and path (and where something like `custom-scheme:` could be a valid URL), the error-less version is actually pretty convenient.

Comment: Indeed the `Separate` makes this. If it doesn't find separator character - it returns empty strings. In such case there is an error, that's why you should check for any errors.

I modified the code so it could track if separator is located at the start of the line.